# How to get value of nested img src with Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get a nested img srcs with Html Agility pack and I've tried multiple things with no success. Basically there are multiple img srcs I need to grab, all are nested. There are 17 of these I need to grab but can't figure it out for the life of me. Here is the barebones html, I need the value of src in the last line:

```
<div class="largeTitle">
    <article class="articleItem" data-id="0000">
       <a href="#blank_link"> class="img">
         <img class=" lazyloaded" data-src="#blank_link" alt="test" onerror="script" 
          src="image_link.jpg">
</a>
</article>

<article class="articleItem" data-id="0001">
       <a href="#blank_link"> class="img">
         <img class=" lazyloaded" data-src="#blank_link" alt="test" onerror="script" 
          src="image_link.jpg">
</a>
</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the url you mentioned in comments, you can do:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("https://www.investing.com/");
var images = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'js-articles')]//a[@class='img']//img");
        
foreach(var image in images)
{
    string source = image.Attributes["data-src"].Value;
    string label = image.Attributes["alt"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{label}\" {source}");
}
```

Comment: This for sure worked but is getting things outside of the largeTitle div, is there anyway to just get those from within that div?

Comment: You can do `//div[contains(@class,'largeTitle')]//a[@class='img']/img`, but there's more than one largeTitle div on that page.

Comment: Your solution is actually perfect, I can come up with something to figure that part out. Thanks again!